# How do I make my Tex output have such font?

Tags: fonts

This question is about font in Tex.

I want to make my Tex output have the font as in this book https://www.math.wisc.edu/~boston/ddt.pdf
but I do not know how.
I have no idea where to begin.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: They are the standard fonts used by LaTeX

Comment: Standard fonts, no need to do anything, (except from removing other font packages, that override the standard fonts usage)

Comment: You could write one of the authors and kindly ask for their preamble. It has been processed with PDFLaTeX.